# MSSQL to MYSQL Linked Server Insert Query Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I did the following

1) Created a linked server from sql server 2008 R2 to mysql

2) Got solution for select,update and delete

3) In case of insert query i got error

***Query :***

```
(without openquery)INSERT INTO Linkedservername...table name values('',);
```

(or)

```
(with openquery)insert openquery(NEWSQL,'select * from bank_list')values('aaa',11);
```

***Returns Error Message:***

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NEWSQL" returned message
>   "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.6.21]Commands out of sync; you
>   can't run this command now". Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 The
>   OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "NEWSQL" could not INSERT
>   INTO table "[NEWSQL]...[bank_list]".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Got it worked by unchecking two checked options by default  in ODBC data source window

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck in ODBC settings tab page Cursors/Results these settings: "Dont't cache results of forward-only cursors" and "Force use of forward-only cursors".